# Associative container with predictable keys: which one to use?

Tags: c++, stl

A simple question, but the answer is not obvious to me: For performance reasons, which map-type (or maybe non map-type?) container should I, from a performance perspective, best use in the following scenario:

- keys are unsigned integer numbers,
- insertions are frequent,
- read access is even more frequent and random access,
- items are inserted with ascending key values (first inserted item has key 0, next one key 1 and so on),
- items are removed randomly (so sooner or later the list of keys will have "holes", as the corresponding items have been deleted). Removal is almost as frequent as insertion.

I hesitate to use `std::map`, as ascending key order and frequent removal seem to imply continuous re-balancing of the search tree, which to me seems to be a waste of performance.

In other words: Can I gain performance from the fact that I know in advance what the keys of the items will be and even the order in which the keys will appear for insertion? (I do not know the total number of items, though.)

Comment: `std::unordered_map` then, aka a hash table.

Comment: If order is not a factor (and it sounds like it isn't) I would consider an unordered_map. if your keyspace is normal and the top-end of node count reaches stability as well, an unordered_map has potential.

Comment: Profile with `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` and see which one works best.

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal" keyspace?

Comment: What are possible values of your keys? If any value in range [0,N) then what is N?

Comment: N is the maximum value of unsigned int, theoretically. Of course, I never have that many items, but it is not improbable that 10000 items are removed and 10000 are inserted (with new keys then, of course).

Comment: By your description your key set is likely fine. Numeric key values tend to produce reasonable hash distributions because the hash function is a simple modulo to the table size. Unless you see your keyset potentially polarizing on small subsets of hash values that in-turn generates long collision lists (and your description suggests it will NOT) you can get a real screaming container out of an unordered_map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do use an `stl::map` -- even if just for profiling to compare with a hash -- you can use your knowledge that "items are inserted with ascending key values" to greatly increase the efficiency of the `stl::map` insertion operation by giving a hint to the insert call:

```
iterator insert ( iterator position_hint, const value_type& x );
```

... where the `position_hint` will be, for example, an iterator to the previous item inserted.

Comment: That's a great itea. I'll compare it to unordered_map.

Answer (score 4):

If memory is not a problem, why not use a `std::vector` of some custom type? You could have the fastest access times, since all elements are in order, and just save a flag if an element is *removed*. Consider this proxy class:

```
template<typename RealType>
class MyProxy {
public:
    RealType instance;
    bool isused;


    MyProxy(RealType) { /* TODO */ }
};
```

Which is then used within your `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<MyProxy<MyRealType> > vec;
```

For a lookup, you just have to check whether the index is within the bounds of the `std::vector` and that the `isused` flag is `true`. For removal just get the element of index `i` and set the flag to `false`. For insertion you have to `push_back` a new instance of `MyProxy<MyType>` instead of `MyType`.

The drawback of this approach is of course, that the `std::vector` is constantly growing, so you have to keep an eye on memory consumption and eventually freeing the `vector`, but this is possibly the fastest method for lookup, insertion and removal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, a persistent item 1 and a hole from 2-10000 will cause a waste of memory. Unfortunately, I cannot rename the keys.

Comment: The "waste" depends on the size of your mapped data. Consider that a map with 10,000 elements is likely to use 30,000 pointers to organize the data. Isn't that also a "waste"?